# How to remove first and last space from text node using Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I just found a problem when viewing a page using Safari. Normally, when I have code like:

```
<a href="someplace.html">
    Someplace
</a>
```

I expect the browser to render the text as a link with no extra content. That's what Chrome and Firefox do. When using Safari though, that's not the case. Safari adds one space before and one after the text, like the following

[image: tag example].

I know Chrome adds space to the inspector too, but that's not the problem. The problem is that Safari actually renders the whitespace, which is a problem if your content breaks into multiple lines,

[image: like this].

Is there a way to prevent this from happening or should I modify my code and put everything in a single line in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: It sounds very IE6 to have whitespace render. It used to happen with images. If you have text-decoration:underline do you actually get a \_Some neat content\_ underline before and after? I would personally always try to be defensive and not have leading and trailing whitespace in a link because I had such issue before

Comment: @mplungjan It's weird. When using "text-decoration: underline" it renders the first space but not the last. It seems to ignore the last one, but fails to do the same with the one at the beginning.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I get this issue in a project using Nuxt but cannot replicate it elsewhere.